# How elasticsearch is implemented at the phycial level

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know how a command to index a document (Put /index/type/id{data}) is executed and how the document is stored at the physical level.I want to know the hardware level meaning of the terms index,type,document,shards.Could anyone please give the hardware level implementation of elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to briefly summarize the important sections of Elasticsearch for you but I definitely recommend you to read [The definitive guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html).

**Brief Summary**

*Inverted Indexes:*

In its essence, Elasticsearch was designed on a technology called Lucene (which was released in 1998 as part of an Apache project). Lucene was designed to create inverted indexes from the documents inserted into the system. Elasticsearch came into play later on to make this system distributed. To be honest, that is where the power of elastic search comes from.

In order to understand Elasticsearch, you first need to understand the indexing in Elasticsearch. Indexing basically means to create an inverted index from a given document. Please read the following link to understand the Inverted indexes.

Link: [Inverted Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html)

*Distributed execution of requests:*

Elasticsearch is a distributed technology which makes it possible to to have multiple different nodes running elastic in the same network. Together all the created nodes forms a cluster.

If you run the GET command on a specific index, you will get the schema information as the following:

```
{
 "mappings": { --> mappings component of the index defines the structure of what fields contain what kind of data
   ...
 },
 "settings": { --> defines configuration settings for an index
   ...
 }
}
```

and if you look at the settings section in detail, you might find something very similar to the following:

```
"settings": {
   "index": {
     "creation_date": "1504387536767",
     "number_of_shards": "5",           
     "number_of_replicas": "1",
     "uuid": "bfVuaeZtTYyWffcqKHOP_w",
     "version": {
       "created": "5050199"
     },
     "provided_name": "noname"
   }
 }
```

number_of_shards: This defines the physical representation of an index. Shards are mainly used to split up the index documents into different chunks.

number_of_replicas: This defines the number of backup shards.

Now lets look at the following schema

```
cluster

|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  node1                    node2                                                                       |
|  |---------------|        |---------------|                                                           |
|  | P0            |        | P1            |  --> P0 is in node1 and its replica(R0) is in node2       |
|  | R1            |        | R0            |      P1 is in node2 and its replica(R1) is in node1       |
|  |               |        |               |                                                           |
|  |               |        |               |                                                           |
|  |---------------|        |---------------|                                                           |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

P represents primary shards

R represents replica shards

In this example, if any of the nodes goes down we can still reach all the data because of the reason that node1 has P0 and R1 and node2 has P1 and R0. This setup also benefits out of load balancing for the data read requests.

This is just a very simple example to give you the idea about how Elasticsearch makes things faster without getting into the details of it.

*Text analysis:*

When we send a document to Elasticsearch, the document goes through an analysis process. This process is the one which creates the inverted index representation and applies filters if there are any (such as stop word removal, lowercasing, stemming and synonyms)

If we index two documents as shown in the example below, elastic ends up creating lucene index table as the following

Example:

doc1 = I think elastic is the next big thing

doc2 = next big thing is in big data

once the analyzer processes these two documents, it creates the inverted indexes as the following

```
  |---------|------------|-----------|
  |  Token  | Exits in 1 | Exits in 2|
  |---------|------------|-----------|
  |I        |     X      |           |
  |think    |     X      |           |
  |elastic  |     X      |           |
  |is       |     X      |     X     |
  |the      |     X      |           |
  |next     |     X      |     X     |
  |big      |     X      |     X     |
  |thing    |     X      |     X     |
  |in       |     X      |     X     |
  |data     |            |     X     |
  |---------|------------|-----------|
```

After creating inverted indexes for the documents, we can search for a word. If we search for the word "elastic", it returns both of the documents. If we search the word "data", it ends up returning the second document.

**Extra:**

*RDBMS to Elasticsearch*

If you are familiar with the relational DBs, the following chart might also help you to understand what sections matches with what information in Elasticsearch

```
 |Elasticsearch|Relational DB|
 |Field        |Column       |
 |Document     |Row          |
 |Type         |Table        |
 |Index        |Database     |
```

*Two different meanings of the word "index"*

It is also worth mentioning that the word "index" is used interchangeably in Elasticsearch. We use the word "index" for two different things in Elasticsearch.

The first one is the time when we refer to an elastic DB. An elastic database is called an index (such as an Animals Index). A database has types in it (In this case, we can have Amphibians, Reptiles and Mammals). Inside the types we have documents and inside the documents we have fields.

The second one is the time when we insert a document into an index. This is called "indexing a document". For example; the following PUT request triggers elastic to index the given document.

```
 PUT /animals/birds/parrot
 {
  "info": "Parrots, also known as psittacines",
  "lifespan": 50,
  "avglength": 3.4,
 }
```

Comment: Hi @mekutr thanks for the response,is my understanding right that when we make a store operation into elasticsearch , only the inverted index of the contents are stored.If so how are the documents are organized when they are retrieved back

Comment: Hi Vignish, when you send a document to elastic, the process goes through an analysis step which is the process in charge of indexing and filtering a document. You can preferably turn this feature off depending on what you need from your application. It is also worth mentioning that elastic automatically create an inverted index out of a given document(it needs to be a string type) if the index settings are not configured. If you have a document that you want to index, elastic automatically creates the inverted indexes and points all the words found in a string to the original document.

Comment: do you mean that elasticsearch will only store the inverted index of my document but and not the original document itself.Also how elastic decides that this particular document must be put into a particular shard.

Comment: could you briefly explain the phrase "every shard is a lucene index" and how is the documents in a single shard being organized and stored as a single unit?

Comment: Hey I added a Text analysis section to my original reply. Please check that out. I think it will help you understanding how things are mapped in elastic

Comment: That is a true statement that "every shard is a lucene index" and we use shards to improve the search performance but on the other hand having too many shards might bloat your system. Let's say we have 200 docs and 2 shards so the elastic will put 100 to the first and 100 to the second as well.

Comment: That made me clear.The only thing that confuses me is that in the example you mentioned the search for "data" will return docid 2.After this how is the original document (doc 2) is being returned.Is it being stored in some where else.How the exact contents of the documents are being returned

Comment: Yes you can say that. I think what I need to clear out is that inverted indexes are different data structures than the actual documents. Once you setup your index, you mostly specify your analyzers on the fields for that index. Once you insert a document into the index, elastic creates the inverted index out of the fields that you specify in the settings section. This way, elastic tokenizes the field sections and map them to the actual documents. Again, this is a highly simplified view of how elastic handles things. I think you need to read the actual code behind to understand the algos.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong , an index is a pointer that points to the actual data on the disk (ie the shard location).Each shard ( a lucene instance) will contain data structures like inverted index and also the actual document structure

Comment: The word index has two different meanings in elastic. I added another section called Two different meanings of the word "index". Please check that out.